# How can I solve an Intellij IDEA servlet error

Tags: java, jsp, intellij-idea, servlets

When developing a project using servlet, I first met a problem: error during artifact deployment. Then I searched the internet and tried every method, but all failed (including deploying tomcat, making the version correspond). It turned out to appear another problem: internal error.So now the server cannot even be started. Of course I deleted the cache. So I beg friends on stakoverflow give me some advice. Thank you very much (this is the first time I posted a question here,show me you hospitality).The following is my error page.

> Error:Internal error: (java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException) D:\System Volume Information
>   java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: D:\System Volume Information
>       at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.translateToIOException(WindowsException.java:89)
>       at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:103)
>       at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:108)
>       at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsDirectoryStream.(WindowsDirectoryStream.java:86)
>       at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.newDirectoryStream(WindowsFileSystemProvider.java:520)
>       at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.newDirectoryStream(Files.java:475)
>       at java.base/java.nio.file.FileTreeWalker.visit(FileTreeWalker.java:300)
>       at java.base/java.nio.file.FileTreeWalker.next(FileTreeWalker.java:373)
>       at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.walkFileTree(Files.java:2839)
>       at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.FSOperations.traverseRecursively(FSOperations.java:231)
>       at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.FSOperations.markDirtyFiles(FSOperations.java:207)
>       at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.BuildOperations.ensureFSStateInitialized(BuildOperations.java:54)
>       at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.buildTargetsChunk(IncProjectBuilder.java:1064)
>       at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.buildChunkIfAffected(IncProjectBuilder.java:965)
>       at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.buildChunks(IncProjectBuilder.java:794)
>       at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.runBuild(IncProjectBuilder.java:376)
>       at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.build(IncProjectBuilder.java:178)
>       at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildRunner.runBuild(BuildRunner.java:139)
>       at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildSession.runBuild(BuildSession.java:288)
>       at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildSession.run(BuildSession.java:121)
>       at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildMain$MyMessageHandler.lambda$channelRead0$0(BuildMain.java:228)
>       at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
>       at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
>       at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:830)
>   Please perform full project rebuild (Build | Rebuild Project)

Comment: Please, add more context, like the code that is causing this exception

Comment: you do not have access to create files in ` D:\System Volume Information`